# google spreadsheet script html service for all

Tags: html, service, google-apps-script, google-sheets, publish

I wrote a google spreadsheet script incl. html service. Now I like to publish the html service as a survey. Everbody shall see it without registration at google but it should be not allowed to see the results of all participants.

Have you an idea how can I reach this?

I tryed a lot of publish options but I didn't reach my goal. Do you?

Comment: Why not just use Google Forms?

Comment: HTML Service isn't Google Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your Apps Script Project is probably bound to the spreadsheet.  If the users who are submitting the form, never need to see the spreadsheet, then create an Apps Script file that is ***not*** bound to anything, it's "**Stand Alone**".  Then do NOT share the spreadsheet.  If you share the spreadsheet, then people who the file is shared with can VIEW the spreadsheet.  It *is* possible to hide and protect sheets and ranges.  And of course you can make settings for some users to be able to VIEW the spreadsheet, and others to EDIT.

If you share the spreadsheet file, then *everyone* it's shared with has VIEW permissions.  You can't share a spreadsheet file and not give VIEW permissions.  **But**, if you want *some* users to be able to see just *some* sheets in the spreadsheet, and not all the sheets, then you would need to write some code that ran when the Spreadsheet opened, and that code would be hiding and unhiding sheets depending on who opened the spreadsheet.  Only users with EDIT permission can unhide a hidden sheet.  So, that's an option.  You can hide a sheet from anyone.  But a user with EDIT permission can unhide the sheet.  If you want to hide a sheet from someone with only VIEW permission, (They can't unhide it) then have code run `onOpen()` that checks the user, checks their permissions and either hides or unhides the sheet.

If the people submitting the form, never need to view the spreadsheet file, then don't even share the spreadsheet URL with those users.  Just use the Stand Alone HTML Service as your "front end", "User Interface" with the users who never need to view the spreadsheet.

So, if the people who are using the HTML don't need to ever view the spreadsheet, then don't give those people the URL to the spreadsheet.  Give them the URL to the published app.  In that scenario, the users of the published app will never see the spreadsheet. The published app is essentially a website, with no real domain name.

The solution for you, depends on how simple or complicated the sharing, editing and viewing settings need to be.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the script file, you need to use the **Publish >> Deploy as web app** option.

Then, choose the version you want to deploy as webapp or create a new one, set the app to execute as you, and add access to anyone (even anonymous). Like this:

[image: Correct Publish settings]

The important thing is that the function that's called when someone access the URL that's shown for your web app, is a function called **doGet()**. So you must rename the function you use to display the UI and Form to doGet(). This function should return a valid HTML Output (normally using the HTMLService or the deprecated UiApp service).

So this:

[image]

Gets you this:

[image]